# Why do we get Non uniform plane waves along a transmission line?

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line

I get that wave propagation will take place but why TEM mode is the only possible mode that can exist? And also why it is non-uniform?

Comment: Who says a TEM mode is the only one possible?  In many transmission lines, there is no TEM mode. And what do you mean by "non-uniform"?

Comment: by "non-uniform" I mean that same phase points have different amplitude